# Big O order of a function

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis

I'm doing some practice questions on Big O notation and came across this question. What is the Big O order of function () = ^2 +  log2() + log2(). Show your working.

My answer is O(n^2) because it's the term with the highest degree. However, I'm not really sure how to show it. Am I right by saying that it has to be proven like this -> f(n) is an element of O(n^2). So far, I've only done questions like n^2 + 2n + 1 and I have to find c and k values. I'm not quite sure how to do this one. Can anyone help me out, please?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to mathematically prove a relation, but it's `O(n^2)`, because `n*n` grows faster than `n*lgn` (and also `lgn`).  So it behaves like `n^2` for large values of `n`.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/ might be better for this question.

Comment: Hint: c=2 and k=1 will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `c := 3` and `k := 1`. Let `n >= k`, i.e. `n >= 1`. We obtain

```
f( n ) = n*n + n*log(n) + log(n)  // definition of f
      <= n*n + n*n      + n      // n >= k = 1
      <= n*n + n*n      + n*n    // n >= k = 1
       = 3*n*n
       = c*n*n
```

which means that `f \in O(n*n)`.